# What does a "3 h5" mean in reference to the axle of a motor?

Tags: abs, pla, 3d-models, print-preparation, motor

Sorry if this isn't the right place to ask, but it seemed like the most relevant stackexchange.

I want to print a connection from a motor to an omniwheel, the axle of the wheel is listed as 8mm, but the one of the motor only say "3h5" which isn't really helpful for me, and neither was Google.

Side-question: Would pla be sturdy enough or do I need to use abs?

Comment: Please refrain from asking multiple unrelated questions in a single answer. To preserve the accuracy and usefulness of the site please create a new question for **Would pla be sturdy enough or do I need to use abs?**. Thank you and welcome to 3D Printing SE!

Comment: Okay, sorry, haven't use stackexchange that much.

Comment: No problem, everyone's new at some point. Glad I could help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's a reference to a tolerance. Look at [this ISO table](http://www.toolingsolutions.com/technical_info/iso_tolerance). This States that the nominal diameter of 3mm is held to a tolerance of +-0.004mm.

@DarthPixel provided some great links identifying the term *interference fit* (or press fit as I've heard locally) as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interference_fit). Also, [here](http://www.eminebea.com/en/engineering_info/bearing/ballbearings/cat-3/004-10.shtml) is a better link providing examples of how the tolerance works and more legible tables to reference the correct tolerance. Keep in mind that the units in the tables is in nanometers.

Comment: exactly. here is [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interference_fit) which describes it and IMO [better (more readable table)](http://www.eminebea.com/en/engineering_info/bearing/ballbearings/cat-3/004-10.shtml)

Comment: Thank you for the references. I was on the mobile app when I posted the answer. I'll add your links to my answer shortly.